# Game Center create account doesn't work ingame

Tags: ios, game-center

When I'm trying to login to game center from my game a popup appears with use existing account/create account. If I tap create account a similar screen like the one from game center - create account appears. In that screen I'm not able to select the country. Every other button is working fine, I can drag and the Locations are moving, but I'm not able to select a country. In GameCenter application I can select a country(the screen seems to be the same). Did you encountered this problem? Do you know possible reasons for this problem?

Thanks!

EDIT1: I tested only on SANDBOX environment

EDIT2: I use to method_exchangeImplementations() to change: touchesBegan, touchesMoved, touchesEnded, touchesCancelled methods to custom functions, but I don't think this is the problem because drag works fine and tapping next button also works fine

Comment: This has worked for me in the past, last time I tested it was about 4 weeks ago. I have not done so since iOS5